# Вынесение общего статического метода в родительский класс

Tags: php, классы

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой простой пример:

```
<?php

class a
{
    protected static $self = false;
    protected function __construct()
    {

    }
}
class b extends a
{
    protected static $self = false;
    public static function build(){
        if(!self::$self){
            self::$self = new self();
        }
        return self::$self;
    }

    public function doSomeThing()
    {
        echo 2;
    }
}
class c1 extends a
{
    protected static $self = false;
    public static function build(){
        if(!self::$self){
            self::$self = new self();
        }
        return self::$self;
    }

    public function doSomeThingElse()
    {
        echo 3;
    }
}
b::build()->doSomeThing();
c1::build()->doSomeThingElse();
```

есть повторяющийся код в наследниках

```
protected static $self = false;
public static function build(){
    if(!self::$self){
        self::$self = new self();
    }
    return self::$self;
}
```

Как то его можно вынести в родительский класс a, не нарушая логики? Например если мы не пропишем `protected static $self = false;` в наследнике, то получим другую логику поведения статического метода `build()`

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема перенести метод build в класс a?

Comment: У вас наверное проблема в том, что вы не знаете про ключевое слово `static` как "синоним" `$this` или `self`. Короче "позднее статическое связывание"

Comment: Ну и наследование синглтонов это что-то не совсем нужное.

Comment: я написал простой пример, в моей задаче( то что здесь выступает в качестве "class a") имеет магический метод __get - при первом обращении к свойству он использует уникальные методы детей чтобы 1 раз залезть в базу и записать данные в свойства класса. А делаю я эту кучу наследников, потому что таблицы будут меняться и обращения по вытаскиванию данных тоже. Поэтому не надо будет лазить по всему проекту и в каждом участке менять обращение к базе данных.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в protected static $self хранился именно объект дочерний, а не объект класса а. Может использовать трейты, магическое свойство __CLASS__, я так и не понял как же его вынести в родительский класс a. Я также пробовал в дочернем прописывать protected static $class_name = __CLASS__; переносить build() в родительский и в нем писать $class_name = self::$class_name; self::$self = new $class_name(); Но он ругался что не может взять self::$class_name из дочернего

Comment: Так как свойство объявлено как `static` то оно доступно во всех инстансах классов. Таким образом изменяя один инстанс - вы изменяете неявно и все остальные.

Answer (score 1):

Ура, нашел способ - избавился от повторяющегося метода и повторяющегося свойства

```
trait build{
    public static function build(){
        if(!isset($build_keeper[__CLASS__])){
            $build_keeper[__CLASS__] = new self();
        }
        return $build_keeper[__CLASS__];
    }
}
class a
{
    protected static $build_keeper = [];
    protected function __construct()
    {

    }
}
class b extends a
{
    use build;
    public function doSomeThing()
    {
        echo 2;
    }
}
class c1 extends a
{
    use build;
    public function doSomeThingElse()
    {
        echo 3;
    }
}
b::build()->doSomeThing();
c1::build()->doSomeThingElse();
```

*правда придется использовать короткую строчку* `use build;` но это уже намного лучше

@u_mulder подсказал ответ лучше

```
<?php
class a
{
    protected static $build_keeper = [];

    public static function build(){
        if(!isset(self::$build_keeper[static::class])){
            self::$build_keeper[static::class] = new static();
        }
        return self::$build_keeper[static::class];
    }

    protected function __construct()
    {

    }
}
class b extends a
{
    public function doSomeThing()
    {
        echo 2;
    }
}
class c1 extends a
{
    public function doSomeThingElse()
    {
        echo 3;
    }
}
b::build()->doSomeThing();
c1::build()->doSomeThingElse();
```

Добавлю [ссылку](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) на то как это работает

Comment: Ну и трейт то зачем использовать в этом случае? Перенесите `build` в родительский класс и используйте `new static()`.

Comment: Работающий пример - https://3v4l.org/VAP53

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо за ответ! Пока сам не столкнулся в лоб с поздним статическим связыванием, думал что о нем знал.